# Comparing LastWriteTime with .txt file

Tags: c#, file, compare

I want to compare LastWriteTime from file on Computer with .txt file on server (for example http://www.vmr.cba.pl/VMR/config_date.txt), I have something like that but it say's that date isn't same however it is

```
WebClient Download = new WebClient();
            string serwer_date = Download.DownloadString("http://www.vmr.cba.pl/VMR/config_date.txt");
            string DateServer = serwer_date;

            path = "yo.txt";
            DateTime test = new DateTime();
            test = File.GetLastWriteTime(path);
            test.ToString("dd-MM-yy-HH:MM");

            if (String.Equals(test, DateServer))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No cheat");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("cheat ;c");
```

Comment: something to do with Time Zones maybe.. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastwritetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) states that the return time is local time.

Answer (score 0):

You call `ToString` function but doesnt get result from it. `ToString` doesn't modify your current object.
Return value of `DateTime.ToString` is a string representation of value of the current DateTime object as specified by format.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

You need to modify this part of your code like this:

```
string dateInString = test.ToString("dd-MM-yy-HH:MM");

if (String.Equals(dateInString, DateServer))
{
    MessageBox.Show("No cheat");
}
```

Comment: nice observation. i missed that one.